# find all the items in the list and log them with url

Tags: javascript, html, logging

I am trying to return all of the items in this html list (its inner HTML and URL of reference).

I could log and find one item, but my `console.log` is not retrieving all of them at once.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('vxl-filelink-text');
var sampleX = document.getElementsByClassName('vxl-filelink-text');
var text; 
sampleX[0].innerHTML;
sampleX[0].href;



for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += "name and url";
}
```

```html
<ul class="vxl-list vxl_1_105_435">
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">duck.png</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">bird.png</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">truck.png</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">car.jpg</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What should I be doing?

Comment: "_need a for loop to get all this data in the console_" - Yes sir. So, you can start by doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to build an array of text/link objects, you can then iterate that array to display all the values, or use it for any other purpose:

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('vxl-filelink-text');

const result = Array.from(links).map(n => ({ text: n.textContent, link : n.href }))

result.forEach(({ text, link }) => console.log(`${text}: ${link}`))
```

```html
<ul class="vxl-list vxl_1_105_435">
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">duck.png</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">bird.png</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">truck.png</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vxl-filelink">
      <div class="vxl-filelink-link-icon vxl_1_106_550"></div><a class="vxl-filelink-text" href="https://yahoo.com/food" target="_blank">car.jpg</a>
      <div class="vxl-filelink-filesize vxl-body-small"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```